# Is Microsoft Solver Foundation bugged?

Tags: c#, ms-solver-foundation

I wrote this infeasible `oml` by mistake while trying to do another thing. What's wrong about it is that the constraint at the bottom is impossible since the minimum value on the right must be zero and the maximum on the left must be bigger than zero (unless of course I'm missing something).

The problem is that if you run it MSF will happily give you an answer instead of telling you is infeasible.

```
string oml = @"
    Model[
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d1],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d2],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d3],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d4],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d5],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d6],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d7],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d8],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d9], 
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d10],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d11],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d12],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d13],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d14],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d15],
        Decisions[Integers[0,Infinity], d16],
        Constraints[d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5 + d6 + d7 + d8 == 2],
        Constraints[d9 + d10 + d11 + d12 + d13 + d14 + d15 + d16 == 2],
        Constraints[d1 + d9 <= 1],
        Constraints[d2 + d10 <= 1],
        Constraints[d3 + d11 <= 1],
        Constraints[d4 + d12 <= 1],
        Constraints[d5 + d13 <= 1],
        Constraints[d6 + d14 <= 1],
        Constraints[d7 + d15 <= 1],
        Constraints[d8 + d16 <= 1],
        Constraints[Max[d1 * 1, d2 * 2, d3 * 3, d4 * 4, d5 * 1, d6 * 2, d7 * 3, d8 * 4] <= Min[d9 * 1, d10 * 2, d11 * 3, d12 * 4, d13 * 1, d14 * 2, d15 * 3, d16 * 4]]
    ]
";

SolverContext sc = SolverContext.GetContext();
sc.LoadModel(FileFormat.OML, new StringReader(oml));
var sol = sc.Solve();
Console.WriteLine(sol.GetReport());
```

**Edit:**

This is what my report gives me:

```
===Solver Foundation Service Report===
Date: 6/26/2012 11:00:55 AM
Version: Microsoft Solver Foundation 3.0.1.10599 Express Edition
Model Name: DefaultModel
Capabilities Applied: CP
Solve Time (ms): 135
Total Time (ms): 338
Solve Completion Status: Feasible
Solver Selected: Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Solvers.ConstraintSystem
Directives:
Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services.Directive
Algorithm: TreeSearch
Variable Selection: DomainOverWeightedDegree
Value Selection: ForwardOrder
Move Selection: Any
Backtrack Count: 0
===Solution Details===
Goals:

Decisions:
d1: 0
d2: 0
d3: 0
d4: 0
d5: 0
d6: 0
d7: 1
d8: 1
d9: 0
d10: 0
d11: 1
d12: 1
d13: 0
d14: 0
d15: 0
d16: 0
```

Comment: Non-constructive but funny as hell

Comment: Which MSF version are you using? I ran your code in MSF 3.1 (build 3.0.2.10889, 64-bit) and I get the report _Solve Completion Status: Infeasible_. Selected solver _ConstraintSystem_, algorithm _TreeSearch_.

Comment: For those of us that are a little lazy, could you provide details on what you think the values are the final constraint check is supposed to be processing?

Comment: @Anders Gustafsson: I just downloaded 3.1 and got infeasible too. I guess 3.0 is just bugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a version problem. When running the same problem in the latest release (standard edition) of MSF, the solver reports the problem as *Infeasible*. Apart from this, the report lists the same properties as the report from 3.0 above, just not the decision values.

So yes, it seems like there is some kind of bug in MSF 3.0. To overcome this bug, try and upgrade to the latest MSF version, 3.1.